# How to maintain aspect ratio using aspect-ratio in a CSS grid on both landscape and portrait layouts

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, aspect-ratio

I have the following elements laid out using both Grid and Flexbox:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the `.inner` elements to be laid out in a 2-by-2 grid with the `.square` elements maintaining an aspect-ratio of 1.

So far I have the following CSS:

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
}
.inner {
  background: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.square {
  background: lightgreen;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This works fine when the width of the viewport is greater than the height (e.g. landscape):

[image: Working fine in landscape]

But when the height is greater than the width (e.g. portrait), the squares overlap:

[image: not working in portrait]

I can fix the issue for portrait by changing `align-items: center;` in `.inner` to `align-items: self` but this then breaks the layout for landscape.

Is there any way I can get it to work on both?

CodePen here: https://codepen.io/danielgibbsnz/pen/KKbWoWL (just resize the window to portrait to see the problem).

---

**Note:** I would ideally like to accomplish this using `aspect-ratio` and not resorting to the padding hack (if at all possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need a wrapper for `.square` with the same `aspect-ratio: 1;`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}
.inner {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.square-wrapp {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.square{
  background: lightgreen;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square-wrapp">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square-wrapp">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square-wrapp">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square-wrapp">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I don't suppose you're able to explain why this is the case? There's enough nested containers here that I don't fully understand what's going on.

Comment: One quick tweak: how would I prevent the title from moving further away from the square in a portrait viewport?

Comment: `.square-wrapp { justify-content: flex-start; }`

Comment: Hmm, that keeps the square and the title together but they're not centred vertically any more. I've played around a bit but haven't succeeded yet...

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work better? (Note: it involves a random width on the square, so may not be what you want.)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}
.inner {
  background: lightpink;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.square {
  background: lightgreen;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This kind of works, but with a viewport wide enough the content overflows the container vertically, which is something I'm trying to avoid.